# Blocking direct access to files (scp or ftp-like behaviour) on ssh server for some users

Tags: ssh, scp, sshd

Is there any way to allow users to only login on terminal shells through ssh ensuring that every connection is gonna run only what's scripted on .profile file?

We wanna block users of accessing the server other than telnet-like terminal sessions running only what's scripted on .profile. So they cannot access files directly through scp/sftp or running any arbitrary commands like `ssh user@server "cat file"`.

This .profile script prepares the current shell (bash) to run a ncurses-based application which is launched with `exec` command (on the current pid).

But only for some given users.

Comment: Yes for `scp` it is in the manual.  As for `ssh user@server "cat file"` will you let them do that interactively? However what are you trying to protect. Tell us your motivation, as this will help us answer.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: is it better now? Let me know if it's better to get another approach to ask this question.

Comment: Look up in the ssh manual, there is a way to tell it that any one using “this” key should run “that” command.

Answer (score 0):

The `ForceCommand` configuration option in `sshd_config` is what you are looking for. I recommend you to set your application there, rather than depending on the `.profile` behavior.

Comment: Then all .profile pre-run-stuff must be put in a new script and in the end a call to the application. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to look into setting `command="whatever"` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for all users. I have not tested it but using `command="/bin/bash .profile"` may get you what you want.

Comment: There is no `command="whatever"` in sshd_config.

Comment: @Jakuje You are correct. `command="whatever"` is an token in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and I had assumed that the option was brought over unchanged.